Automatically use another font as the italic type
I've got a question about something that could make my life a lot easier.
I'm using Word in Office 2021 to write documents and I write texts with the Times New Roman font. When I have to write with the italic type, like the name of a book, which I do pretty often, I always use another font: Brush Script MT.
Here's what I'd like to do: it would be pretty handy if I could just write in TNR and turn to Brush Script just by activating the italic knob.
Does anyone know how to do something like that ?

It wouldn't be too hard to record a macro that changes font. Just start the macro recorder, change font to normal and another for the italics, and when both macro's are recorded, give them a shortcut key or macro button in the toolbar, which ever you prefer. Now you can switch with one press of a two buttons. If you are really skilled, you could even program that the pressing of the button toggles between italics and not.

look into styles. I believe word supports character styles which allow you to style portions of a paragraph.

Thank you for your interest. OK for looking into macros, it's a first step. But is it possible that Ctrl+I switch to my italic macro, just when I'm already writing in Times New Roman?

Yes, but simpler would be to modify the built-in Emphasis character style to include your font preference. Then use the style.
You can add the font to the style. Assign the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+I to the style.
To modify the style apply the Emphasis style to include your font in Word, select a word and change the font as desired. Select the word and right-click the Emphasis style name in the Gallery or the Styles Pane and pick "update Emphasis to match formatting."

If you want to have this available in all new documents, right-click on the style name again and check the box to have it in new documents based on the template. (This assumes that the attached template is the Normal template.)
When you want to return to your underlying paragraph style's non-Italic TNR, press Ctrl+Spacebar.
Here is my article about assigning keyboard shortcuts in Word.
Here is my page about the Importance of Styles in Word.

Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't suspect the Styles section to be so rich, I'm reading your page about that right now. Anyway, it works like a charm.
